# Find duplicates based on a unique value in one column

Tags: sql

I am looking for a solution to the following:

Table T has X, Y and Z columns.  Columns X, Y and Z have multiple duplicates amongst themselves but not accross columns.  I need to query Table T to find all rows with value V in Column Z, then use column X and column Y of that row to find duplicates.

I want to search for all rows with an R in column Z and return any rows that have a duplicate X and Y of that result.

Comment: Homework or not, the question reflects no research whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

To find all duplicates:

```
select x, y, count(*)
from mytable
where z = ?
group by x, y
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X,Y,Count(Z)
FROM T
WHERE Z=@R
HAVING Count(Z)>1
```